# How to use the "Azure Storage Container URL" returned by the PNS Feedback service?

Tags: azure-storage

I'm trying to get feedback for push notifications, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt705560(v=azure.100).

> Upon success, an Azure Storage Container URL is returned, complete with authentication token.

I have the URL:

```
https://pushpnsfb9bf61499e7c8fe.blob.core.windows.net/00000000002002698042?sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&sig=KbF1GtORNzAaCZH9UP7UFi9wMOYBmBgL%2BXLG3Qau9U0%3D&se=2020-08-29T19:10:17Z&sp=rl
```

But requesting it returns an authentication error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature...</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was... </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I am trying to follow the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-service-sas-create-dotnet?tabs=dotnet#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob-container. The URL has `sr=c`, which seems to mean I need a "SAS for a blob container".

But where do I get the token? The returned URL has a `sig` querystring parameter - I tried using that to sign the request, but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you want to do with the container url?

Comment: @JimXu, I am trying to make a request to that URL to get a list of expired device tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call the Get Platform Notification Services (PNS) feedback rest api, we will get a container url with sas token. And the sas token has read and list permissions at container level. So we can use azure blob rest api to read the content, properties, metadata or block list of any blob in the container or list blobs in the container with the token. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-container)

For example

1. Get container url
   [image]
2. Test
   a. list blobs

```
GET https://pushpnsfb2f34ecd6733e74.blob.core.windows.net/00000000002000276266?
<sas token e.t. sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&sig=SQodHcRM6p04ag9rJZBqPDmr1NMd%2FbIWoPzMZrB9TpI%3D&se=2020-09-02T05%3A28%3A07Z&sp=rl>
 &restype=container&comp=list
```

[image]

b. read blob content

```
GET GET https://pushpnsfb2f34ecd6733e74.blob.core.windows.net/00000000002000276266/<blob name>?
<sas token e.t. sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&sig=SQodHcRM6p04ag9rJZBqPDmr1NMd%2FbIWoPzMZrB9TpI%3D&se=2020-09-02T05%3A28%3A07Z&sp=rl>
```

For more details about Azure Blob rest api, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api).

Comment: That worked, though I'm not sure where the "&restype=container&comp=list" came from, I thought I was supposed to just use the URL as-is. After appending those args to the querystring, it started working. Thanks!